# Is covariance preserved under transformation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2$ be normally distributed random variables with $\rho = 0.5$, mean equal to $0$ and variance equal to $1$.

Let $U_i = \Phi(X_i)$ where $\Phi$ is the marginal distribution of $X_1,X_2$. We know that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are then correlated.

Is it true that $E[U_1 U_2] = 0.5$? I am just curious I've been looking at various books but can't find anything related to this.

I just happened to think of this as I was about to simulate correlated random variables for an experiment.

Comment: It seems like you might be confusing random variables with their distributions. What do you mean by $\Phi(X_i)$ where $\Phi$ is the marginal distribution? Distributions are functions on sets, not on real numbers.

Comment: As far as I can tell it seems like $U_1$ and $U_2$ are not well-defined, but I may be misunderstanding you, which is why I am asking for clarification.

Comment: $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF, so $U_1,U_2$ are uniform on the unit interval.

Comment: Oh I thought OP meant the distribution itself, not the distribution function. That makes a lot more sense, thank you.

Comment: In general, covariance is bilinear, but thats about it for how it generally behaves under transforms.

Answer (score 2):

No. By your definition, $U_1,U_2$ will be both uniform on the unit interval. Then, by Holder's inequality $E[U_1U_2]\leq (E[U_1^p])^{1/p}(E[U_2^{(1-1/p)^{-1}}])^{1-1/p} = \left( \frac{1}{p+1} \right)^{1/p}  \left( \frac{1}{\left(1-1/p \right)^{-1} +1} \right)^{1-1/p}$ for all $p\geq 1 $.

Now, plot the upper bound, and see that there exists a $p$ such that it is less than a half. In fact, using $p=2$ (Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) gives the upper bound of $\frac{1}{3}$ (which is the tightest you can get just by optimizing over $p\geq 1$).

Comment: Good idea +1; The question does confuse correlation with $E(U_1U_2)$ of course.